# Word automatically opening documents from previous session

Tags: microsoft-word

I have been facing this issue with Microsoft WORD automatically opening documents from the previous session ("Previous Session" -- refers to a time before the shutdown or restart of the system). This happens even if I have closed each word document before the shutdown or restart.

Found some discussion in Microsoft forum regarding the same ([click here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-automatically-opening-documents-from-previous/6a04b368-aab8-4f57-814a-ec02bd072cd2?page=2)) but of not much help.

Any ways to rectify the issue?

OS/Word Versions

- Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044
- Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2205 Build 6.0.15225.20362) 32-bit

Comment: Please [edit] the tags to include your operating system/version and your word version.

Answer (score 1):

While solution cannot be found yet, I found the workaround.

1. Backup document (Note the file location)
2. Delete document there
3. It should notice a new Recover file would open when Word 365 is re-opened
4. Close that file

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the solution in this post, which seems to work: [Is there a way to stop MS Word from automatically opening previously opened documents?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56684/is-there-a-way-to-stop-ms-word-from-automatically-opening-previously-opened-docu)

Answer (score 0):

THat article you linked is for Macs not Windows so not helpful.  If you don't know the answer don't waste everyone's time ya think?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190810)

Comment: Also, if you're referring to the link in the OP that says "click here", the link goes to a post called "Word for Windows", not Word for Macs.